# Angular 6 | RouterLink

Tags: angular, typescript, router-outlet

is there any way to go to another page's section  which is defined by id without reload

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, this is not a coding service. To read how to ask question please read [ask], and edit your question accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using scrollIntoView method

Credits goes to:ibenjelloun

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-spy-routing

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event: any) {
    let currentSection: string;
    const children = this._el.nativeElement.children;
    const scrollTop = event.target.scrollTop;
    const parentOffset = event.target.offsetTop;
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        const element = children[i];
        if (this.spiedTags.some(spiedTag => spiedTag === element.tagName)) {
            if ((element.offsetTop - parentOffset) <= scrollTop) {
                currentSection = element.id;
            }
        }
    }
    if (currentSection !== this.currentSection) {
        this.currentSection = currentSection;
        this.sectionChange.emit(this.currentSection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a bunch of new scrolling features added in Angular v6.1.

Here is a quote from a blog post about it:

> The Router Scroller provides functions related to scrolling to the
>   Angular Router. With Router Scroller, you can do the following things.
>
> Restore to scroll position before transition when browser back
>   Fragmented URL like `#foo` and automatically scroll to elements with
>   corresponding ID

I assume the second paragraph (anchor scrolling) is what you are asking about?

If so, you can find out more here:

https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/introduce-router-scroller-in-angular-v6-1-ef34278461e9

And

https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/07/26/what-is-new-angular-6.1/